# Need Explanation in Java Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

This is my code, I need an explanation of how this code works `result=fact(n-1)*n;`.My expected answer was not same as the output.I think after the return the stack should executing resumed state,the first execution state is 
`n=2` and `(2-1)*2=2`, then `n=3,(3-1)*3=6`, then `n=4,(4-1)*4=12`, then `n=5,(5-1)*5=20`.
The final answer I expected is 20. How did I get 120? How is the stack working in this scenario?. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Factorial 
{

int fact(int n)
{
    int result;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    result=fact(n-1)*n;
    System.out.println("value of n="+n);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
}

class TestFact
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Factorial ob=new Factorial();

    System.out.println("Final="+ob.fact(5));
}
}
```

The output of the given program is

value of n=2

2
value of n=3

6
value of n=4

24
value of n=5

120

Final=120

Comment: This is why debuggers exist.  Spend some time learning how to use one.  If you are using an IDE for your work, then all of them have a debug capability.

Comment: Recursion is an ancient concept, there's _plenty_ of material out there already to help you learn. Once you learn it, you might find yourself solving problems in quite creative ways.

Comment: Factorial of 5 is 120. You code is fine, you are just confused about what factorial is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: I know that, I just want to know the internal working of this code.

Comment: @Enrique_Iglesias, in your question you say that you expect 20 but the output is 120, so it is clear that you don't know that the code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the method of calculating the factorial.

The method is defined as below for every `n >= 1`:

[image]

**Cases:**

1. fat(1) = 1 (by definition)
2. fat(2) = 2 * fat(1) (result on item 1) = 2 * 1 = 2
3. fat(3) = 3 * fat(2) (result on item 2) = 3 * 2 = 6
4. fat(4) = 4 * fat(3) (result on item 3) = 4 * 6 = 24
5. fat(5) = 5 * fat(4) (result on item 4) = 5 * 24 = 120

The algorithm is correct. You just misunderstood how factorial is calculated.

**Improved code for better outputting**

```
public class Factorial{
  int fact(int n) {
    int result;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    result=fact(n-1)*n;
    System.out.println("Fat(" + n + ")=" + result);
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Factorial fat = new Factorial();
    System.out.println("Final=" + fat.fact(5));
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU8xDsIwDNz7CqtTDKJSByaUlY2pI2IwpaBAcKvGBSHE24ubgNgY4tgn3/nuTDdatF3D58NlHLth710NtacQYEOOnxmAY4Ej1WKmhhEmLKF9EwYvqzQfDVtbooIy9AxlgtOKjXxelDjjhFePIM21aAcpul61PJt8TWJymAPry9FObaLjVysq/66@Mi0fz0FI9Lu17gBXdW4qUd3TdgfUnwIm01MkzSJggZt7HA3@MeSYfPShnCJmWCKmy69sHN8)

Comment: I got my mistake.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is completely wrong.

Results of fact() function is `1, 2, 6, 24`. So to get final result you need to multiply 1*2*6*24=120.

See [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)